# Regex in C++ how to search for valid Linux Device Node?

Tags: c++, regex, linux, c++11, std

Given a device node in Linux such as "/dev/sda1" or "/dev/sdb", I'd like to match all valid choices to know if I have a valid device node.

Here's what I have so far:

```
static bool isUSBNameValid(const std::string &node) {
    std::regex device("/dev/sd[a-z]*");

    if (std::regex_match(node, device)) {
            return true;
    }   

    return false;
}
```

This does not work. Why is this?

How to make this work with any valid Linux device node?

Comment: Simply because you are matching `[a-z]` and digits are left out. Try with `[a-z0-9]`

Comment: Are you trying to match some specific devices or [all](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apds01.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`/dev/sd[a-z]*`](https://regex101.com/r/6r49Ew/1) pattern matches `/dev/sd` literal substring followed with any 0+ lowercase ASCII letters. Used within `regex_match`, *the pattern must match the whole string*. Since the `/dev/sda1` ends with a digit, the `regex_match` fails, but it succeeds with `/dev/sdb`.

So, if you plan to only match SATA devices, you will need to use `/dev/sd[a-z][0-9]*` pattern, else, to match arbitrary number of alphanumeric chars after `/dev/`, you may use `/dev/[[:alnum:]]+`.

```
std::regex device_sata("/dev/sd[a-z][0-9]*");
std::regex device_any("/dev/[[:alnum:]]+");
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/m77srj):

```
#include<regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isUSBNameValid(const std::string &node, std::regex device) {
    if (std::regex_match(node, device)) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main() {
    std::regex device_sata("/dev/sd[a-z][0-9]*");
    std::regex device_any("/dev/[[:alnum:]]+");
    cout<< ( isUSBNameValid("/dev/sda1", device_sata) ? "Found" : "Not found")<<endl;
    cout<< ( isUSBNameValid("/dev/sdb", device_sata) ? "Found" : "Not found")<<endl;
    cout<< ( isUSBNameValid("/dev/ttyS0", device_any) ? "Found" : "Not found")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what worked. Only caveat is that I added this one to match one or more numbers and zero or more letters at the end of the string:

    std::regex device_sata("/dev/sd[a-z]+[0-9]*");

Comment: @FrederickOllinger You can easily deduce it from my patterns. You may also use `"/dev/sd[[:alnum:]]*"`, it is actually matching `/dev/sd` and then 0+ letters or digits. Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following pattern instead:

```
std::regex device("/dev/sd[a-z][0-9]*");
```

Add capturing groups around the [a-z] and [0-9]* if that becomes important.

If you truly want to match any device it would be:

```
std::regex device("/dev/[[::anum]]+");
```

with an additional check that what you have matched is not a directory. It would probably be good to add such a check (using stat) anyway.

Comment: You're missing a bracket in the first expression.